# How to compare two distributions, where the numbers in each distribution are proportions?

Tags: chi-squared-test, proportion

Could anyone suggest a statistical technique for comparing two distributions, where the numbers in each distribution are proportions?

I have two distributions, each of which reports the proportion of entities in one of 12 classes. Unfortunately, I don't know much about the sample size for one of these distributions, so I'm comparing them on the basis of proportions: I can do so visually, but I'd also like to do so statistically. I'd use the chi-square test for equality of proportions, were the numbers in each distribution counts. In this case, the null hypothesis would be that the distribution of classes is essentially the same. However, I don't think this test is appropriate in this case. Could anyone suggest an alternative?

Comment: Without some sample size information, I don't see how much can be done. If the proprtions are rounded fractions, you might be able to compute lower bounds on the possible sample sizes based on the values the proportions take, but those lower bounds aren't likely to be very helpful (in the sense that fairly low sample sizes are likely to be consistent with the figures, implying you won't be able to tell any differences from random variation).

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Glen_b. Useful information, even if nothing can be done.

Comment: Just as an example, if you has two proportions, 0.84 and 0.48 (84% vs 48%), which you know to be fractions rounded to the nearest whole percent, then those *are* significantly different because the smallest $n$'s that would produce those values (16/19, 10/21) are large enough that you can tell them apart on any of the usual tests. [The reason you need some idea of sample size in the first place is that the uncertainty associated with the estimate of population proportions depends on sample size.]